# missing prototype error

Tags: c

I'm getting an error I don't understand and can't find a solution.

The error is as follows:

missing prototype for isANumber

the code it refers to is:

```
double prompt(char *promptString) {

    printf("%s", promptString);
    char *input = "";
    scanf("%s", &*input);
    printf("%s\n", &*input);

    int check = isANumber(input);


if (check) {
    return (double) *input;
} else {
    return 0.00;
}

}

int isANumber(char *check) {

    int result = 0;    /* Current isdigit() return value */
    do                           /* Check that each character of the...*/
        result = isdigit(*check++);  /* ...string is a digit and move on...*/
    while (result && *check);       /* ...until non-digit found or at EOS */
    return result;  /* Return result of last isdigit() call */

}
```

libraries included:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't forward reference like that. You need to declare or define `isANumber` before you can reference it:

Put this before your `prompt` function:

```
int isANumber(char *check);
```

Answer (score 1):

declare the prototype *before* the use:

```
int isANumber(char *check);
```

or (simpler) swap the functions

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the prototype for

```
int isANumber(char *check) {
```

Which should be:

```
int isANumber(char *);
```

at the top.

Comment: The parameter name is optional in a declaration.  You can write either `int isANumber(char *);` or `int isANumber(char *check)`, whichever you prefer.  (I prefer the more explicit version.)